# He is good enough "on" or "in" English?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which is correct?

> He is good enough on English.
>
> He is good enough in English.

Intuitively I will use on, but second thought make me feel both the same, or is it bizarre to use "good enough" in this way in the first place?

Comment: Of the two, *in* would be more natural. However, I would use *at* over either.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is the correct one.

> "In" can be used to describe a belief, opinion, or **object of interest**.

For example:

- I'm interested in you.
- I believe in god.

"On" has its own use cases.

For denoting position:

> I set a pencil on my desk.

For referring to device:

> He is on the phone.

Or for talking about the state of something:

> The house is on fire.